# Drag drop actions get passed but action doesn't happen in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium 3.141

Chrome and Firefox browser

---

I'm trying to drag drop object between two fields on a web application using selenium.

I notice drag/drop field getting highlighted which confirms dragdrop fields are correct and I see some action which highlights scrollbar but object doesn't gets dropped.

```
WebElement source = fromfield.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@title,'task1')]"));
WebElement tofield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-field-name,'task2')]"));
highlight(source)
highlight(tofield) //both dragdrop fields gets highlighted
Actions maction=new Actions(driver);
maction.dragAndDrop(source, tofield).build().perform();
//tried below alternative way of dragdrop by increasing/decreasing pause duration but no success
maction.clickAndHold(source).pause(2000).moveToElement(tofield).pause(2000).release().build().perform();
```

Expected Result: DragDrop should happen between fields

Actual Result: Drag/Drop fields are highlighted and dragdrop actions get passed but object doesn't gets dropped.

After inputs from Infern0, tried with below code snippet but getting an exception.

```
String js_filepath = "C:/test/drag_and_drop_helper.js";
 String java_script = null;
 String text = null;
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(js_filepath));
 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
 while ((text = input.readLine()) != null)
        buffer.append(text + " ");
        java_script = buffer.toString();
 jse.executeScript(java_script+"$('#{objectProperty_c77}').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#{objectProperty_c76}'});");
```

js reference: https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544#file-drag_and_drop_helper-js

**Exception: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier**

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between manually drag-drop and using selenium. 
I had similar issue, element is getting highlighted (obviously should be moving) but no. This was caused because javascript events, that are being triggered in behind.

Issues god solved with using native javascript events for doing the drag and drop. You can find such implementations in the web.

Comment: Thank you. As per your suggestion. I found drag_drop_helper.js created by rcorreia and I tried below code snippet but got org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier  jse.executeScript(java_script+"$('#{objectProperty_c77}').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#{objectProperty_c76}'});");

Comment: Obviously, your locator is in not in the proper format.

Comment: @Inferno Thanks. $('#objectProperty_c77').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#objectProperty_c76'});"). I tried with this but I get $ not a function error. Here objectproperty_c76 77 are the ids of the source and target webelement.

Comment: @DebnjanB Can you please provide your input on html5 dragdrop in selenium java?